# Array find_index returning nil even though value is clearly in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm working on this programming challenge from Coderbyte:

> Using the Ruby language, have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

My code is as follows:

```
def LetterChanges(str)
  alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
  result = ""
  str = str.each_char do |c|
    idx = alphabet.find_index(c)
    if idx != nil
      idx == 25 ? idx = 0 : idx += 1
      c = alphabet[idx]
      c.upcase! if ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?(c)
    end
    result << c
  end
  return result 
end
```

When I run the code for LetterChanges("coderbyte") it returns 'dpEesczUe'. I did some testing and realized alphabet.find_index("e") would return nil. However when I run the code LetterChanges("eeeee") it returns 'fffff' as expected. There must be something I'm missing I just can't figure out what!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing:

```
c = alphabet[idx]
```

which is taking one of the characters from `alphabet`

and then doing `c.upcase!` which will modify that entry in `alphabet` so after the "d" of "coderbyte" `alphabet[4]` (the "e") has been changed to "E" so when you try to find "e" in `alphabet` it isn't there any more.

Lots of ways to rework the code slightly to solve this but one would be to change to use `c = alphabet[idx].dup` or to change to an approach where you can use `upcase` instead of `upcase!`

Comment: Glad to help. Imagine it was seeming very strange :)

Answer (score 2):

a simpler implementation

```
def LetterChanges(str)
    str.tr('a-z','b-zA').gsub(/[aeiou]/){|c| c.capitalize}
end
```